# Android - Button with rotating/spinning 'loading' image when pressed

Tags: android-animation, android

I have a big 'Log in' button on my app. When the user taps this button, I want to replace the text with 'Logging in...', align it to the left instead of center and put a spinning circle on the right (but still inside the button). I'd like to use essentially the same button (but with different initial and loading text) in other places in my app.

What's the neatest way to do this? For the actual spinning graphic, I was planning to use the `@drawable/spinner_white_16` that comes with Android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own button using a RelativeLayout containing a TextView and an ImageView.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    onClick="[yourLoginMethod]" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/login_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Log In" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/login_loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/login_text"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in whatever your login method is called, change the contents of the TextView, make it align parent right, and set the ImageView visibility to visible.

```
loginText.setText("Logging In...");
LayoutParams params = loginText.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
loginText.setLayoutParams(params);
loginLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And then I would also have some code that reverses those changes if the login fails.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an implementation that I came up with, hopefully its reusable:

[ProgressButton](https://github.com/SundeepK/ProgressButton)

At the moment, when the user clicks the button, it will display the drawable (and animate) for you but you will have to dismiss the loading animation manually once you've finished with your background task via:

```
_progressButton.stopLoadingAnimation();
```

This will dismiss any animation for you and display any previous text that was there. The only thing missing it that there is no text whilst the animation is in progress, but I think you can hack something together for that. I plan on extending this a little further so that it will allow you to call something like `_progressButton.setProgress(10)` and then set the percentage that is done. I may even make it thread safe.

This way you don't have to use multiple layouts and embed any textviews on top of buttons, and its all handled for you.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own button, which will consists of a centered `TextView` and `GONE` `ImageView`. After click move `TextView` to the left and make `ImageView` with your drawable visible.