# Android login button hide on press

Tags: android, authentication

I'm doing an android login. Its uses a simple validations and if validated it calls a method to call the api.

code:
..

```
if(!Validate.isEmailAddress(inputEmail,false)){
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Enter proper email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    validated = false;
}
else if(!Validate.hasText(inputPassword)){
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    validated = false;
}

if(validated){   
    btnLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    loginLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password); 
             // check for login response
    try {
         if (
```

But setVisibility is not working here. It stays till the login process completed. The login process is taking more than 15 secs. So i need to show user a loading image in the place of the login button

Please help. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

use `AsyncTask` instead .. check simple example [here](http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/10319834334/simple-asynctask-example-in-android)..

You can display `progress dialog` during the login progress... sample [here](http://rorraja.blogspot.com/2012/03/show-progress-dialog-inside-asynctask.html)

Answer (score 0):

you are setting

```
validated = false;
```

in both the cases.. so `validated` is always `false`.

Check if you set the validated flag to true properly before that...

Comment: Thanks, its declared as true and made false if not validated. Its working if i comment this line:  JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

Answer (score 0):

You run login process in UIThread, it may be in background thread.

Comment: thanks, is that not possible to hide a btn and to show a loading image. Actually i wanted to follow this: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269546/android-button-with-rotating-spinning-loading-image-when-pressed [/link]